# Jquery addclass on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this structure

```
<div class="container">
  <a> <img /> </a>
  <div id="actions"></div>
 <ul id="add-to"> </ul>
</div>
```

and I'm using a script like this

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#actions, #add-to").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).prev('a').addClass('opacity');
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).prev('a').removeClass('opacity');
    });
});
</script>
```

it does work when hover on the actions element id, but not with the #add-to.

Can you help me with this?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)** only select immediate previous element, `a` is not immediately previous to`#add-to`. In this case you can use **[`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** or **[`prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/)** . while using **[`prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/)** use **[`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)** to get closest one

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#actions, #add-to").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).siblings('a').addClass('opacity');
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).siblings('a').removeClass('opacity');
    });
});
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#actions, #add-to").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).prevAll('a').first().addClass('opacity');
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).prevAll('a').first().removeClass('opacity');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Or `.prevAll().first()` to get the closest preceding element.

Comment: @Barmar : since only one element `first()` can be avoided .. is it?

Comment: The HTML in the question could be just a minimal example, maybe the real HTML has more anchors in the DIV.

Comment: `.prevAll('a').first()` does what he presumably thought `.prev('a')` would do.

Comment: @Barmar but while using `prevAll()` which one will be first element?

Comment: They're ordered from closest to farthest, it's in the jQuery documentation.